# Get the current cursor position value in RichTextBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-3.0

How do I get the current cursor position value in `RichTextBox` in WPF?

There are a lot of changes in `RichTextBox` in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`CaretPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.caretposition.aspx) property.

This gets (or sets) the position of the input caret.

In addition there's the [`Selection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.selection.aspx) property. This returns an object that holds information about the selected text including it's [`Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange.start.aspx) and [`End`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange.end.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

hi hope this code might help you

Code:

```
private static int EM_LINEINDEX = 0xbb;
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
extern static int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int message, int wparam, int lparam);
private void UpdateCaretPos()
{
  int line, col, index;
  index = rtfText.SelectionStart;
  line = rtfText.GetLineFromCharIndex(index);
  col = index - SendMessage(rtfText.Handle, EM_LINEINDEX, -1, 0);
  panCaret.Text = (++line).ToString() + ", " + (++col).ToString();
}
private void rtfText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  UpdateCaretPos();
}
private void rtfText_KeyDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  UpdateCaretPos();
}

private void rtfText_KeyUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  UpdateCaretPos();
}
```

Regards

**Karan Shah**

Comment: sorry mate, have to downgrade, it is WPF, it is bad karma to use win32 API. WPF has in built support to get mouse pointers.

Comment: Upvote, you solved my problem with Windows Forms RichTextBox :)! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
    {
        var z = this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        var r = richTextBox1.Find(" ", 0, z, RichTextBoxFinds.None | RichTextBoxFinds.Reverse);
        var q = this.richTextBox1.Text.Substring(r + 1, z - r - 1);
        switch (q)
        {
            case "test":
                this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = r + 1;
                this.richTextBox1.SelectionLength = z - r - 1;
                this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
                this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart += this.richTextBox1.SelectionLength;
                this.richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
                //e.Handled = true;
                break;
            default:
                this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = z;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```